# Change unique item in FlatList using ExtraData

Tags: react-native

I have on flatList that renders 5 TouchableOpacity. I want to change borderColor from the one I press in my flatList without changing the other, and do it with index that saved in `state`

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data} keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    numColumns={columns}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
        if (item.empty) {
            return <View style={[Cards.item, Cards.itemEmpty]} />;
        }
        return (<View style={[{ flex: 1 }]}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressChangeColor(item.id)}
                style={[Cards.item, {
                    backgroundColor: "grey",
                    borderColor: "grey",
                    borderWidth: 2
                }]}>
            <Text style={[{ color: "white", textAlign: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }]}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>);
        }
    }
/>
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read.

Comment: I think it's better now...
Can you help me?
Sorry about hard read code.

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: I want to change borderColor from the one TouchableOpacity when I press it in my flatList without changing the other.
I don't know how a do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the unique TouchableOpacity:

save the index in state:

```
state = {
    index: null
}
```

save the unique index in`onPressChangeColor` function like this:

```
onPressChangeColor = (id,index) => {
     //do what you want with the id
     this.setState({index})
}
```

and the `FlatList` with some changes:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data} keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    numColumns={columns}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        if (item.empty) {
            return <View style={[Cards.item, Cards.itemEmpty]} />;
        }
        return (<View style={[{ flex: 1 }]}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressChangeColor(item.id, index)}
                style={[Cards.item, {
                    backgroundColor: "grey",
                    borderColor: index == this.state.index ? "green" : "grey",
                    borderWidth: 2
                }]}>
            <Text style={[{ color: "white", textAlign: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }]}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>);
        }
    }
/>
```

Comment: My Friend!!!!
Thank you very much!!!

It works!!!

I just needed to add extraData={this.state} to borderColor be activated!!

Thank you again!!!!!